# Call Function From Procedure in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I'm trying to check if a service that I just installed is running or not before exit in Inno Setup. I need to execute a program just after so I am trying to call a procedure that uses a function from BeforeInstall in a run parameter.

I found this example from another post and I'm trying to alter it to check if my service is running after it installs but before the run line is executed. I'm new to pascal and I can't seem to work out how to call the function from the procedure. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
[Run]
; Launch the Setup App here
Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; BeforeInstall: AfterInstallProc

[Code]
procedure AfterInstallProc;
begin
  result := not IsAppRunning('MyService.exe');
  if not result then
    MsgBox('Error message here', mbError, MB_OK);
end;

function IsAppRunning(const FileName : string): Boolean;
var
  FSWbemLocator: Variant;
  FWMIService : Variant;
  FWbemObjectSet: Variant;
begin
  Result := false;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WBEMScripting.SWBEMLocator');
  FWMIService := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('', 'root\CIMV2', '', '');
  FWbemObjectSet := FWMIService.ExecQuery(Format('SELECT Name FROM Win32_Process Where Name="%s"',[FileName]));
  Result := (FWbemObjectSet.Count > 0);
  FWbemObjectSet := Unassigned;
  FWMIService := Unassigned;
  FSWbemLocator := Unassigned;
end;
```

Comment: Your code seems fine to me, other than your mentioning you want to do things before install and your code is in the `AfterInstall` procedure (which executes *after the installation* and therefore the name *AfterInstall*). What specific problem are you having with it?

Comment: I get an Unknown Identifier error on IsAppRunning on this line: result := not IsAppRunning('MyService.exe');

Comment: That information should have been in your question, and then I wouldn't have had to ask. Keep that in mind in the future. :-) If you don't tell us what the problem is, we don't know - we can't see your screen from where we're sitting. Providing the details you already have makes it easier for us to help, and it gets you that help more quickly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the arrangement of your code so that `IsAppRunning` is known before `AfterInstall` tries to use it - otherwise the compiler doesn't know it's there. (It doesn't look ahead, but neither does Delphi's compiler.)

You also have a second problem (which isn't apparent from your question). Procedures don't have the pre-defined `Result` variables that functions do, because procedures don't have results. You'll also need to declare a local variable in your `AfterInstallProc` procedure to avoid a `variable "Result" is not declared` error.

```
[Run]
; Launch the Setup App here
Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; BeforeInstall: AfterInstallProc

[Code]
function IsAppRunning(const FileName : string): Boolean;
var
  FSWbemLocator: Variant;
  FWMIService : Variant;
  FWbemObjectSet: Variant;
begin
  Result := false;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WBEMScripting.SWBEMLocator');
  FWMIService := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('', 'root\CIMV2', '', '');
  FWbemObjectSet := FWMIService.ExecQuery(Format('SELECT Name FROM Win32_Process Where Name="%s"',[FileName]));
  Result := (FWbemObjectSet.Count > 0);
  FWbemObjectSet := Unassigned;
  FWMIService := Unassigned;
  FSWbemLocator := Unassigned;
end;

procedure AfterInstallProc;
var 
  Result: Boolean;
begin
  Result := not IsAppRunning('MyService.exe');
  if not Result then
    MsgBox('Error message here', mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm still getting an error though. Unknown Identifier 'result' on this line: result := not IsAppRunning('MyService.exe');

Comment: `Result` is only pre-defined for functions, not procedures. One sec.

Comment: Yeah that's the error I've been struggling with the most. I tried adding a global var but then it kept telling me it was a duplicate.

Comment: See my edit. I asked for a second, didn't I? :-) You didn't give it to me.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I'm still getting the duplicate identifier error though in the procedure here: procedure AfterInstallProc;
var 
  Result: Boolean;

Comment: So name the variable something other than `Result`. Try `Res`. It's not a duplicate in any of the code you posted, so it's probably something else you've done somewhere (like with your global declaration attempts).

Comment: Thank you so much! I need to spend some time learning the rules of pascal, just in a hurry to get it working right now. Very much appreciate all your help.